# How do I use jQuery to assign a path to a button?

Tags: jquery

I have a photo [gallery page](http://ee.rouviere.com/photo_portfolio/) that shows a series of thumbnails that are pulled from a database. The images link to a larger preview image which is displayed when the user clicks on the thumbnail.

I also have a **buy this photo** button which needs to be linked as something like this:

> http://ee.rouviere.com/photo/image/entry_url

Where the entry url is the title of the entry.

The jQuery code I am using is:

```
$(function() {
    $("a:has(img.gallery)").click(function() {
        var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
        var caption = $(this).attr("title");

        $("#photo_large").attr({ src: largePath});
        $("#caption1").text(caption);
        return false;
    });
});
```

I just need some help integrating the buy now button into this:

Here is the html for the button:

```
<div id="buy-this-photo">
<a href="http://ee.rouviere.com/photo/image/Leaf_stains_on_sidewalk">
       <img src="http://ee.rouviere.com/_images/btn_buy-this-photo.jpg" 
            alt="Buy This Photo" /></a>
</div>
```

I need to make the href portion dynamic so it reflects the link the current entry.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you should be able to add this line above the return false to do what you want:

```
var urlTitle = caption.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_');
$('#buy-this-photo a').attr('href', 'http://ee.rouviere.com/photo/image/' + urlTitle);
```

This should convert the title to the url title according to that template.

You could also stick the url title on as a separate attribute or metadata and use that instead.

Comment: This is very close. However, the caption is the title of the entry. There is also a url_title which works like this: if the title is Little Red Riding Hood, the url_title is little_red_riding_hood. Is there some way to pull in the url_title?

Comment: Hi IB, we are thinking along the same lines. I did this and it worked: misc="{site_url}photo/image/{url_title}" however, the validator doesn't like my use of misc. Is there another attribute that would validate and accept a url?

Comment: I would recommend you use the metadata plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata 
This will allow you to put the url into the class attribute and read it from there while passing validation. Feel free to ask if you need any help using it.

Comment: IB, I put in the metadata plugin and it worked perfectly. Problem solved. I would give you 100 more points if I could. Thanks for the extra effort.